# How do I force the content of a child element with "flex-grow: 1" to overflow the parent instead of the child?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a `display: flex` parent with some height depending on the viewport height and it has multiple children. Most of the children have their height based on their contents, but one of them will have a lot of content and so it should take all the available space with `flex-grow: 1`.

This element however also has a number of children, only one of which should take the available free space and and this one child should also have a `min-height`. If there isn't enough space - the out-most parent should overflow, instead of its child with `flex-grow: 1`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 80vh;
}

.long-child {
  flex-grow: 1;

  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.inner-long-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="static-child">
        <h1>This is a short child</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="static-child">
        <h1>This is a short child</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="long-child">
        <div class="inner-static-child">
          <h2>Inner short child</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-long-child">
          <p>Long content</p>
          <p>Long content</p>
          <p>Long content</p>
          <p>Long content</p>
          <p>Long content</p>
          <p>Long content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="static-child">
        <h1>This is a short child</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can find a simplified example in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-shadow-tmlk85?file=/index.html)

What I want is for `parent` to overflow instead of `long-child` if there is not enough height to satisfy `inner-long-child`'s min-height property.

Or, to put it another way - how do I force a flex item  with flex-grow to respect its content's min-height and not shrink further than that? I thought `flex-basis: content` should do exactly that, but it doesn't seem to work.

Edit: the idea is for `inner-long-child` to be exactly the available flex-grow space until it goes down to its min-height. If there is a longer content inside it, it would `overflow-y: auto`, which flex-shrink breaks.

Comment: flex-shrink: 0 ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif An important clarification - the `inner-long-child` has to be exactly the available flex-grow space until it goes down to its min-height. If there is a longer content inside it, it should `overflow-y: auto`, which flex-shrink breaks. I will now edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ into your question; please do not just send us to some external platform.

Comment: So - `overflow: auto` on the parent then, _instead_ of on `.inner-long-child`, and without the `min-height` for `.long-child` ...? Is this the behavior you want -> https://jsfiddle.net/x73bradh/ ?

Comment: No, I am trying to achieve the same behavior as this: https://jsfiddle.net/pk8s3rqe/ but with one additional level of nesting a flex item with flex-grow: 1. As you can see, `long-child`'s height is `max(<available height>, <min-height>)`. The idea is to stop `long-child` from shrinking when `inner-long-child` reaches it's min-height